# How to select the first file in a directory?

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to process some files in a directory without knowing their name, and one by one.
So I've used `os.listdir(path)` to list files.

So I have to list files at each call of my function. The problem is when there is a lot of files (like 2000), it takes a loooooong time to list each file and I just want the first one.

Is there any solution to get the first name without listing each files ?

Comment: Which one is the first file? And also, if you are using an os like linux, having lots of files in a directory can in itself slow down things. If you go into it with a file viever or just ls, it, it could take quite a long time

Comment: I will process every one of them, so I don't really care which one will be the first. Basically, just one of them would be enough. I won't have to list them through ls or a file viewer so it doesn't bother me for now. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I meant the api functions from the os don't have O(N) notation, they are slower then that. Once you get beyond a certain amount of files, it is quicker to just move some into different directories just to speed up these apis.

Comment: Oh ! Ok. So classing them into different directories would be a good thing for speed. I'll do that. Thanks !

Comment: Can't you refactor your function so it doesn't have to get the list every time?

Comment: That's what I'll have to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your goal is to process each file name, use os.walk() generator:

```
Help on function walk in module os:

walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
    Directory tree generator.
```

Comment: Seems to be what I want (with a `break`), I'll test that soon. Thank you.

Comment: @Lerenn did you manage to just find just one file without having to go through the entire file list? If so can you direct me on how to do it?

Comment: @SuryaPalaniswamy The easiest way would be to `walk` until you find your file, then `break` so it doesn't traverse further

Comment: @dtasev I don't really have a specific file per se. I wanted it for a project to just randomly select one file from a folder and move it elsewhere and do this for a given iterations. Since the files were to too long to list and then move I wanted a way to just randomly pick a file without having to list all.

Answer (score 24):

```
os.listdir(path)[0]
```

It would be faster than 'listing' (printing?) each filename, but it still has to load all of the filenames into memory. Also, which file is the first file, do you only want whichever one comes first or is there a specific one you want, because that is different.

Comment: I already thought about that, but the program continues to list files internaly and slow down the process :/

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you're trying to process the files en masse, and you'll be iterating through all the files at some point. Instead of having calling the method every time that you enter your function, why not have a global parameter so that you only load the list once? So, for example, instead of:

```
import os
def foo(path):
    os.listdir(path)[0]
```

you have:

```
import os
fnames = os.listdir(path)
def foo(path):
    fnames[0]
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I was expecting for, because my function return an object for each file and new files can appears during the execution. But I think will do as you say : list all of them, process all of them and return a list of objects. Thank you btw!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for now ... (15 required)

Answer (score 2):

To get the first filename without having to scan the whole directory, you have to use the walk function to get the generator and then you can use next() to get the first value of the generator.

```
folder_walk = os.walk(path)
first_file_in_folder = next(folder_walk)[2][0]

print(first_file_in_folder)
# "firstFile.jpg"
```

Comment: This solution still scans the whole directory (that is why there is a [0] in the second line).

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7:

```
import os

def get_first_file_path(path):
    first_file_path = None
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        if len(files) > 0:
            first_file_path = os.path.join(root, files[0])
            break
    return first_file_path
```