# How to find the first image in a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-os

What I want to achieve is to get the first item in a folder that is a jpg or png image without having to scan the whole folder.

```
path = os.getcwd()
#List of folders in the path
folders = next(os.walk(path))[1]

#Get the first element
folders_walk = os.walk(path+'\\'+ folder)
firts = next(folders_walk) [2][0]
```

With this code I get the first element of the folder, but this may or may not be an image. Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Select the first file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613409/python-select-the-first-file-in-a-directory)

Comment: The order of files in a file system directory is arbitrary, so wanting the "first" one (or the first one of a certain type) is somewhat meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "without having to scan the entire folder". You could use `glob()`, but that would still scan the entire directory to match the regex.

Anyway, see a solution below. Can easily modify if you don't want a recursive search (as below) / want a different criterion to determine if a file is an image.

```py
import os 

search_root_directory = os.getcwd()

# Recursively construct list of files under root directory. 
all_files_recursive = sum([[os.path.join(root, f) for f in files] for root, dirs, files in os.walk(search_root_directory)], [])

# Define function to tell if a given file is an image
# Example: search for .png extension.  
def is_an_image(fpath): 
    return os.path.splitext(fpath)[-1] in ('.png',)

# Take the first matching result. Note: throws StopIteration if not found
first_image_file = next(filter(is_an_image, all_files_recursive))
```

Note that the above will be much more efficient (in the recursive case) if `sum()` (which pre-computes the entire list of files) is omitted and instead a list of files is handled in `is_an_image` (but the code is less clear that way).